# Azure AD B2C identity providers

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I need to investigate if and how we can manage the selection of identity providers per tenant in B2C. 
I know that we can manage that by creating custom policies per each tenant. This is the way that we should follow?
Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by tenant? Are you referring to AAD tenants, or do you mean something else? In B2C IDPs are provisioned per AAD tenant regardless, so users will only see the IDPs for the tenant in which they are trying to authenticate.

Comment: Yes, I mean AAD tenants

Answer (score 0):

I think that is the way to go  . You want to put that logic **away from your application**. Moving the logic into custom policies will also allow you to reuse it in any other application.

Comment: Do you also know what is the answer to these questions: • During log in, users should only see identity providers which are configured for that specific tenant. Is this possible and if so, how? - we should create custom policies for each tenant?
• Is it at all possible to disable local accounts for all or for a specific tenant?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have much experience with custom policies but I think that it would be possible to only see identity providers for a specific tenant if you create custom policies for each tenant.