# Dynamically show Identity providers using Azure B2C custom policy

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I would like to show Identity providers dynamically based on the tenant[ i.e OIDC domain_hint] during the Azure B2C *Sign In* user journey. I have referred several examples on `custom policies`, however unable to find a way to display/hide an IdP based on tenant. I was able to use this good [example](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-developer-community-blog/advanced-home-realm-discovery-in-azure-ad-b2c/ba-p/482788) to do Home Realm discovery in custom policy using an Azure Function, but it doesn't show 'list of IdP' applicable for the tenant/domain. Other SO questions, that came close to this but didn't answer are [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52362246/azure-ad-b2c-identity-providers), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70862854/using-dynamic-identity-providers-with-azure-b2c). Even if I serve custom HTML file from blob storage, how to show only certain Identity providers and hide some based on the tenant/domain_hint ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of domains/tenants permutations, you could put that logic on the application side to execute different PolicyID's. This is assuming the number is low therefore it would be a policyID : IdPs mapping.

This is a bad solution if you have a HIGH volume of hints.

Alternatively, you could perform an [API call via JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36975619/how-to-call-a-rest-web-service-api-from-javascript) to delegate populating the list of Identity Providers. Then, it would execute another self-assertive page that would trigger that specific identity provider. The flow would look like:

App (passes domain hint)--> B2C login page (JavaScript REST API on page and request list of IdP's based on previous domain hint) --> 2nd Self-assertive page (value passed from first page to initiative the correct IdP) --> IdP pages load.

You can adjust the logic in different ways to meet your needs.

Comment: It is not a handful of tenants[hints] situation for me, and so this will not work for me. Even the Ops team would not allow to create as many policies as number of tenants :-).  As you say if there are others with such scenario, your approach would work.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the tenant in a claim using [claim resolvers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview), then have an orchestration step for each possible combination of IdPs you want and use preconditions on those steps to only execute them depending on the tenant. Hopefully that works.

Comment: Unless authentication is completed, there are no `claims `available to do any such logic. This doesn't solve my question.

Comment: I'm confused about your issue. [This example](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/unit-tests/blob/main/claims-resolver/CR_OIDC.xml) demonstrates getting the OIDC domain hint prior to any authentication. You'll have to add a technical profile as the first step in the user journey to get the claims, but the claims should be available immediately.